# Can the google vision api recognize code text (e.g. javascript) from an image?

Tags: google-api, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

Can the OCR recognize characters like the equals sign, braces '{}' and parentheses? Is it accurate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can.
Here you can just try it in browser for free without registration:
https://cloud.google.com/vision/

Comment: Thank you for the link. I tried it with a zoomed in snapshot (larger font, hoping that would help it detect more characters) of some javascript code. Did not turn out very well... It did not detect all of the equal signs as well as other symbols that are not commonly used in regular language but are used in coding.

Comment: @Aryeh, I won't be surprised if it would work better on a good photo than on screenshot.